# Aggregate values from array of JSON objects based on timestamp

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, timestamp

I am relatively new to programming and javascript and i want to achieve the following.
Let's assume that we have the following data:

```
let data =
  [
    {
      "time": 1663163352001,
      "state": "10"
    },
    {
      "time": 1663163352002,
      "state": "20"
    },
    {
      "time": 1663163354002,
      "state": "10"
    },
    {
      "time": 1663163354002,
      "state": "10"
    },
    {
      "time": 1663163355033,
      "state": "30"
    },
    {
      "time": 1663163355035,
      "state": "10"
    },
    {
      "time": 1663163397035,
      "state": "30"
    },
    {
      "time": 1663163397044,
      "state": "50"
    }

  ]
```

i want to aggregate and calculate the averaged state based on timestamps on time interval (let's say 1 second)
so the output should be

```
let data =
  [
    {
      "time": 1663163352000,
      "state": "15"
    },
    {
      "time": 1663163353000,
      "state": "0"
    },
    {
      "time": 1663163354000,
      "state": "10"
    },
    {
      "time": 1663163355000,
      "state": "20"
    },
    {
      "time": 1663163356000,
      "state": "0"
    },
    {
      "time": 1663163397000,
      "state": "40"
    }

  ]
```

I know my code is not right but at this is the logic that i have already implement.

```
//Inputs
var t_interval = 1000;


let aggregatedValues = [];
let count = 0;
let sum = 0;
//starting point converted in seconds
t0 = data[0].time - data[0].time % 1000;
//the timewindow
t_win = t0 + t_interval;

//Just for this case 
for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

  if ( data[i].time < t_win) {
    count += 1;
    sum += parseFloat(data[i].state);
  } 
  else{
    if (sum === 0 || count === 0) {
      avg = NaN;
    }
    avg = sum / count;
    count = 1;
    sum = parseFloat(data[i].state);

    let temp = {
      "time": t_win - t_interval,
      "state": avg
    }
    aggregatedValues.push(temp);
    t_win = t_win + t_interval;
  }
  
}
```

Could you help me please?
Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your code? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Why do you fill in the gaps at `1663163353000` and `1663163356000` with values of zero, but not fill in all the gaps between `1663163356000` and `1663163397000`?  or is that last really supposed to be `16631633`5`7000`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple task, `reduce` over your collection to create an object with `key` = `timestamp` and `value` = `object` of `total amount of states` and `count` of met items. Apply some rounding operation on timestamp. Then 1 more loop to calculate average values. Convert it back to array and sort (if needed). Gaps filling is up to you.

```js
const data = [
  { time: 1663163352001, state: "10" },
  { time: 1663163352002, state: "20" },
  { time: 1663163354002, state: "10" },
  { time: 1663163354002, state: "10" },
  { time: 1663163355033, state: "30" },
  { time: 1663163355035, state: "10" },
  { time: 1663163397035, state: "30" },
  { time: 1663163397044, state: "50" }
];

function aggregate(items) {
  const step = 1000 * 1; // 1 second

  const resObj = items.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const roundedTimestamp = Math.round(item.time / step) * step;
    const parsedValue = parseInt(item.state, 10);

    const existing = acc[roundedTimestamp];
    if (!existing) {
      acc[roundedTimestamp] = {
        count: 1,
        value: parsedValue
      };
    } else {
      existing.count += 1;
      existing.value += parsedValue;
    }

    return acc;
  }, {});

  const res = Object.entries(resObj)
    .map(([key, value]) => ({
      time: parseInt(key, 10),
      value: (value.value / value.count).toString()
    }))
    .sort((a, b) => a.time - b.time);

  // fill gaps if you really need that.
  //

  return res;
}

console.log(aggregate(data));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what if the step changes ?

Comment: @ΘοδωρήςΣουλτανόπουλος Step is used to round `time` to closest.. Im not really sure how to tell, but in this case it will round to closest second,  values like `1663163352001`, `1663163352002`, `1663163352049` will be rounded to closest step-based value `1663163352000` in this case. If you change it to `1000 * 60 * 5` - it will be rounded to closest 5 minutes based value, i.e. 00:00, 00:05, 00:10 and etc. Rounding used is `Math.round` which rounds value to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 0):

Here I make the assumption mentioned in my comment that the last value in your input was a typo.  If not, I don't understand something fundamental.

By breaking out reusable functions to group elements by the result of a function and to create an integer range, we can turn this into a reasonably simple function:

```js
const groupBy = (fn, k) => (xs) => xs .reduce (
  (a, x) => ((k = fn (x)), (a [k] = a[k] || []), (a[k] .push (x)), a), {}
)

const range = (lo, hi) => Array .from ({length: hi - lo + 1}, (_, i) => i + lo)

const group = (interval) => (
  data,
  groups = groupBy (({time}) => Math .floor (time / interval)) (data),  // or Math.round
  keys = Object .keys (groups) .map (Number),
  min = Math .min (...keys), max = Math .max (...keys),
) => range (min, max) 
  .map (k => [k, groups [k] || []]) 
  .map (([k, v]) => [
     interval * k, 
     v .reduce ((t, g) => t + Number(g.state), 0) / Math .max (v .length, 1)
  ])
  .map (([time, state]) => ({time, state}))


const data = [{time: 1663163352001, state: "10"}, {time: 1663163352002, state: "20"}, {time: 1663163354002, state: "10"}, {time: 1663163354002, state: "10"}, {time: 1663163355033, state: "30"}, {time: 1663163355035, state: "10"}, {time: 1663163357044, state: "50"}]

console .log (group (1000) (data))
console .log (group (2000) (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We use `groupBy` to turn the input into a structure like this:

```js
{
    "1663163352": [{time: 1663163352001, state: "10"}, {time: 1663163352002, state: "20"}],
    "1663163354": [{time: 1663163354002, state: "10"}, {time: 1663163354002, state: "10"}],
    "1663163355": [{time: 1663163355033, state: "30"}, {time: 1663163355035, state: "10"}],
    "1663163357": [{time: 1663163357044, state: "50"}]
}
```

then grab the keys of this object, turn them into numbers, find the minimum and maximum values, create the integer range between them, and map them back into entry-style objects, using the lists of matching values to fill them, defaulting to an empty list.

We then convert the keys back to full Date values and average the `state` values for each, and turn the resulting array of arrays back into an array of objects.